Abnormalities regarding out of memory:!!! Exception during processing !!! Allocation on device 0 would exceed allowed memory. (out of memory)
In my ComfyUI project, tasks such as generating videos from images and generating videos from text are often performed, which can easily cause video memory overflow. Therefore, when I detect video memory overflow, I called an interface in the easy-use component of ComfyUI to clean up the video memory. As a result, an error occurred. Please help me analyze it:
This is the error report:
This is the relevant pseudo code:
if out of memory:
    SystemResourceManager.clear_queue()
    SystemResourceManager.clear_gpu()



    @classmethod
    def clear_gpu(cls):
        try:
            url = f"{cls.base_url}/api/easyuse/cleangpu"
            req = urllib.request.Request(url, method="POST")
            with urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=10) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    import gc
                    gc.collect()
                    print("cleargpu success！")
                else:
                    print(f"cleargpu failed: {response.status}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"cleargpu have error: {e}")

!!! Exception during processing !!! Allocation on device 0 would exceed allowed memory. (out of memory)
Currently allocated     : 21.96 GiB
Requested               : 416.62 MiB
Device limit            : 23.50 GiB
Free (according to CUDA): 31.69 MiB
PyTorch limit (set by user-supplied memory fraction)
                        : 17179869184.00 GiB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 323, in execute
    output_data, output_ui, has_subgraph = get_output_data(obj, input_data_all, execution_block_cb=execution_block_cb, pre_execute_cb=pre_execute_cb)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 198, in get_output_data
    return_values = _map_node_over_list(obj, input_data_all, obj.FUNCTION, allow_interrupt=True, execution_block_cb=execution_block_cb, pre_execute_cb=pre_execute_cb)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 169, in _map_node_over_list
    process_inputs(input_dict, i)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 158, in process_inputs
    results.append(getattr(obj, func)(**inputs))
  File "/root/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI-CogVideoXWrapper/nodes.py", line 844, in process
    latents = pipeline["pipe"](
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI-CogVideoXWrapper/pipeline_cogvideox.py", line 615, in __call__
    noise_pred = self.transformer(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/transformers/cogvideox_transformer_3d.py", line 429, in forward
    hidden_states = self.patch_embed(encoder_hidden_states, hidden_states)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/embeddings.py", line 440, in forward
    embeds = embeds + pos_embedding
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: Allocation on device 0 would exceed allowed memory. (out of memory)
Currently allocated     : 21.96 GiB
Requested               : 416.62 MiB
Device limit            : 23.50 GiB
Free (according to CUDA): 31.69 MiB
PyTorch limit (set by user-supplied memory fraction)
                        : 17179869184.00 GiB

Got an OOM, unloading all loaded models.
Exception in thread Thread-2 (prompt_worker):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 323, in execute
    output_data, output_ui, has_subgraph = get_output_data(obj, input_data_all, execution_block_cb=execution_block_cb, pre_execute_cb=pre_execute_cb)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 198, in get_output_data
    return_values = _map_node_over_list(obj, input_data_all, obj.FUNCTION, allow_interrupt=True, execution_block_cb=execution_block_cb, pre_execute_cb=pre_execute_cb)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 169, in _map_node_over_list
    process_inputs(input_dict, i)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 158, in process_inputs
    results.append(getattr(obj, func)(**inputs))
  File "/root/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI-CogVideoXWrapper/nodes.py", line 844, in process
    latents = pipeline["pipe"](
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/custom_nodes/ComfyUI-CogVideoXWrapper/pipeline_cogvideox.py", line 615, in __call__
    noise_pred = self.transformer(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/transformers/cogvideox_transformer_3d.py", line 429, in forward
    hidden_states = self.patch_embed(encoder_hidden_states, hidden_states)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/diffusers/models/embeddings.py", line 440, in forward
    embeds = embeds + pos_embedding
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: Allocation on device 0 would exceed allowed memory. (out of memory)
Currently allocated     : 21.96 GiB
Requested               : 416.62 MiB
Device limit            : 23.50 GiB
Free (according to CUDA): 31.69 MiB
PyTorch limit (set by user-supplied memory fraction)
                        : 17179869184.00 GiB

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/main.py", line 126, in prompt_worker
    e.execute(item[2], prompt_id, item[3], item[4])
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 503, in execute
    result, error, ex = execute(self.server, dynamic_prompt, self.caches, node_id, extra_data, executed, prompt_id, execution_list, pending_subgraph_results)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/execution.py", line 407, in execute
    comfy.model_management.unload_all_models()
  File "/root/ComfyUI/comfy/model_management.py", line 1100, in unload_all_models
    free_memory(1e30, get_torch_device())
  File "/root/ComfyUI/comfy/model_management.py", line 441, in free_memory
    if current_loaded_models[i].model_unload(memory_to_free):
  File "/root/ComfyUI/comfy/model_management.py", line 347, in model_unload
    self.model.unpatch_model(self.model.offload_device, unpatch_weights=unpatch_weights)
  File "/root/ComfyUI/comfy/model_patcher.py", line 459, in unpatch_model
    self.model.to(device_to)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1160, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 810, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 810, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 810, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 833, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1158, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid argument
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

I don't know if it is caused by the cleaning function of this component. At present, I am also reading the relevant code.
The address of this component is：https://github.com/yolain/ComfyUI-Easy-Use.git
